# Mathematica returns DSolve exactly as I gave it

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations as follows:

`DSolve[{y''[t] * x[t] + β * x'[t] * y'[t]  + k^2 * y[t] == 0, 
   (x'[t])^2  - x[t] (α * ((y'[t])^2 - k^2 (y[t])^2) - l/(x[t])^2) == 0},
   {x[t], y[t]}, t]`

But Mathematica spits out the exact input as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That means Mathematica cannot solve it!

Comment: Is there any way to make it solve them?

Comment: Try to solve it numerically with NDSolve for special parameter values and initial conditions. The second ode looks like an energy expression, could you provide some additional information?

Comment: If only life is as easy as everything can be solved analytically! Try `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 4):

`DSolve` does yield symbolic solutions for `α == 0`, and those solutions are real for `l <= 0`.  So, for convenience, set `l == -m`.

```
DSolve[{y''[t]*x[t] + β*x'[t]*y'[t] + k^2*y[t] == 0, 
    (x'[t])^2 - x[t] (α*((y'[t])^2 - k^2 (y[t])^2) + m/(x[t])^2) == 0} /. {α -> 0}, 
    {x[t], y[t]}, t]

(* {x[t] -> (3/2)^(2/3) (-Sqrt[m] (t - C[3]))^(2/3), 
    y[t] -> 2^(1/6 (-3 + 2 β)) 3^(1/6 (3 - 2 β)) BesselJ[1/4 (-3 + 2 β), 
        ((3/2)^(2/3) k (-Sqrt[m] (t - C[3]))^(2/3))/Sqrt[m]] C[1] 
        (-Sqrt[m] (t - C[3]))^(1/6 (3 - 2 β)) + 
            2^(1/6 (-3 + 2 β)) 3^(1/6 (3 - 2 β)) BesselY[1/4 (-3 + 2 β), 
         ((3/2)^(2/3) k (-Sqrt[m] (t - C[3]))^(2/3))/Sqrt[m]] C[2] 
        (-Sqrt[m] (t - C[3]))^(1/6 (3 - 2 β))} *)
```

and a second solution with `Sqrt[m] (t - C[3])` replaced by its negative (i.e., time reversed).  A typical numerical solution with `α == 0` is

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[t]*x[t] + β*x'[t]*y'[t] + k^2*y[t] == 0, 
    (x'[t])^2 - x[t] (α*((y'[t])^2 - k^2 (y[t])^2) - l/(x[t])^2) == 0, 
    x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1} /. {α -> 0, β -> 1, k -> 1, l -> -1}, 
    {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

It, of course, also has two solutions, the first of which terminates at about `t == 2/3`, because `x[t]` vanishes there.  The second is

```
Plot[Evaluate[Last[s] // Values], {t, 0, 20}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x, y"}, LabelStyle -> {Medium, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

Because this system of equations is autonomous (as well as time-reversible), there may be other ways to make progress, but I have not been successful in finding them.

Comment: In this solution, when you say $\alpha$ -> 0, does it mean replace $\alpha$ with 0 or as it tends to 0?

Comment: @SgrA  I mean set α to zero, and I shall modify my answer to make this clear.

Comment: But wouldn't that be a problem, if you set $\alpha$ to zero, you're switching off all the terms it's multiplied by?

Comment: @SgrA  If you wish a completely general solution, then specifying a particular value for any of the parameters is a limitation.  Setting `α` to zero is the least I could do and still obtain a symbolic solution.  I suspect that there is no completely general symbolic solution for this pair of ODEs, but who can say for sure.  Describing the situation in which this system arises and the character of the answers you expect could be helpful in making further progress..